# Стабильный connect, reconnect для TCP [qt5]

Tags: qt5

Подскажите как сделать на qt5 стабильный connect. Чтобы при обрыве, reconnect(илось).

Answer (score 3):

`QAbstractSocket` имеет сигнал `error`, подсоединяйте к нему слот, в котором пытайтесь восстановить соединение.